# Is there a R function for easily displaying text as in the Question (i.e. help) function

Tags: r

I need to present the user with some text as in the help function. The help function display the text in a convenient way (for example, in emacs it uses a new buffer, in terminal opens vim, etc). So, is there a function that receives the string and does this job?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to display/what you have alredy tried?

Comment: I want to display some documentation I get as plain text, but that is not an issue. I tryied the menu function which prompt the user with a message, but it's not what i'm looking for, beacuse y prompts for a choice, and it is not my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer asking in the R mail list, and so I update this post with it. As the 'help' function uses 'utils:::print.help_files_with_topic' for printing, looking at it's code it can be found the function 'file.show' that does what the question asked for. It have a 'pager' argument in which it can be specified a system command to run for display.